# Entity can still be selected after deleted by hibernate in transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a method to delete record by hibernate. I add a query after deletion. And the record deleted is still in the result list. It should not be.  Here is the code.

```
@Transactional
public void deleteFoo(long fooId){
    Foo foo = fooDao.find(fooId);
    fooDao.delete(foor);
    List<Foo> brothers = fooDao.findByParentId(foo.getParentId());
    // I think the brothers does not contains foo.
    // Unfortunately, foo is still in the list.
    // I do not know why and how to make sure the brothers does not contains foo.
    ...
}
```

The record is deleted from database where the transaction committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should flush the hibernate session.

When your work with database via Hibernate you are using Hibernate session.

Hibernate sessions flushed to the database by following three situations.

- commit()- When you commit a transaction
- Before you run a query
- When you call session.flush()

or you can flush it manually by

```
session.flush()
```

Comment: Why it wasnot flushed delete but before findByParentId?

Comment: I mean a query against the database.

Comment: I added `session.flush()` after delete. But it caused the deletion committed immediately. It destroyed the transaction config.

Comment: set hibernate.connection.autocommit = false

Comment: @sbjavateam I am using `spring-boot`. And I tested `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.autocommit=false`. It did not work. I do not know is it the correct key.

Comment: I changed the dataSource `BasicDataSource` and set `defaultAutoCommit=false`. It worked. Thank you.